# "Happy median" versus "happy medium"

Tags: phrases

Which is more correct and/or common "Happy Median" or "Happy Medium"? Any history on the two would also be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase is *happy medium*. Here is NOAD's take:

> **happy medium**
>   *noun*
>   a satisfactory compromise : *you have to strike a happy medium between looking like royalty and looking like a housewife.*

Etymonline [says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=happy%20medium&searchmode=none):

> Happy medium is the "golden mean," Horace's *aurea mediocritas*.

So apparently it comes to us through classical scholarship.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to suppose *happy medium* in any way derives from *golden mean*, which is essentially a geometric/mathematical concept. The *happy medium* is all about finding a 'middle ground' which doesn't *exactly* satisfy most parties, but at least has the merit of not being *too* far away from *anyone's* ideal.

Comment: Googling this one shows that people have been confusing the 'standard' *medium* version with the equally meaningful *median* version for years. Personally I don't see any reason to think *median* is in any way 'incorrect' - it's just (so far) less common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm sure plenty of people do use it on the internet, but I would guess it's far less common in educated writing (COCA gives 80 uses of *medium* to zero for *median*). A good reason for avoiding it - especially as the *median* version doesn't seem to convey any different meaning - is that educated speakers will usually just assume you don't know the original phrase :)

Comment: @psmears: You're quite right. I really meant I don't see *much* reason, not *any*. Your reason is certainly enough to make *me* stick to the standard. But looking to the future it wouldn't surprise me if the alternative eventually took over. Whilst it doesn't exactly convey extra or different meaning, it does seem somewhat more 'precise'.

Comment: @Fumble: the *golden mean* is unfortunately used as a translation for two different classical concepts: the mathematical ratio and the philosophical idea of 'Nothing in excess.'  Nobody has yet found a better English phrase for either.

Comment: @TimLymington: I think context would normally make clear which meaning you intended. But if you needed to be explicit, *golden ratio* and *happy medium* are perfectly common non-ambiguous alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

It is **medium**, not median.

Here's a [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/happy%20medium) link.

The earliest example of the phrase that I've been able to find of that particular phrase is an article in the [Perth Magazine of Knowledge and Pleasure](http://books.google.com/books?id=aGcEAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA65&ots=LDkoMwEpEj&dq=All%20extremes%20are%20ridiculous%3a%20the%20happy%20medium%20is%20to%20be%20aimed%20at.&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=All%20extremes%20are%20ridiculous%3a%20the%20happy%20medium%20is%20to%20be%20aimed%20at.&f=false), published in 1772. The use of the word "medium" as a bridge between two extremes goes back to the late 16th century.

Median is primarily a mathematical term, but is sometimes confused with medium due to its similar sound and somewhat similar meaning. Interestingly, they also both come from the same Latin root, "medius," which simply meant "middle".

Answer (score 1):

`Medium` is a richer concept than `median`, and so using the former conveys a more colorful expression.

Where *median* is a simple quantitative concept (the mid-point in a series of numbers), *medium* has some philosophical connotations.  It literally means (Latin) "the thing in the middle", but it has two overlapping senses which may apply here:

1. a conduit, or substance through which other substances move or act (eg, space is the medium of gravity)
2. a bridge, something that contains elements of two opposites, that is able to unite them

So *happy medium* conveys a sense of connection -- harmonious balance -- evoking also (as TimLymington mentioned in a comment) the golden mean of Greek philosophy.  The poetry of the phrase gets lost entirely when "median" is substituted.

Answer (score -1):

The correct term is "happy median" referring to the middling result of a list of numbers.  If the central number, say number 5 out of 9, is skewed higher by 4 more outlying numbers above than below, say for your house value at assessment, then you would have a favorable or "happy" median.  It is clearly a statistically-based term, a happy medium being related to a person who channels the dead spirits and enjoys their work or circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

In order to choose between *happy **median*** and *happy **medium*** one must understand the etymological, formal, and colloquial usages of the two phrases:

- *Happy medium* is a complete phrase in and of itself, while *happy median* is a partial phrase, shortened from *happy median point*.
- *Median*, as used in the phrase is not a noun, but an adjective defining an unspoken but understood noun, such as for example a *point, place,* or *locus*. (Others are possible, too.)

After the two preceding points are grasped, it is up to the one writing as to which is preferred.  Often *happy median* is considered somewhat more refined, as it requires a rather more erudite knowledge of the English language.

Comment: I’m not sure about the “somewhat more refined” thing.  They aren’t normally applicable to the same cases, and *happy median* as applied to the statistical sense of being the point above and below which exactly half the set lies is at best a word play on *happy medium*.